# $O(G)=p^2 $, $p$ prime, $|Z(G)|>1$; prove $G$ abelian

Tags: abstract-algebra, abelian-groups, cyclic-groups

We know that $Z(G)<G,\;$  then $O(Z(G)) \mid  O(G). $

If $\;O(Z(G))= p^2, $ then $\;Z(G)=G$ and we are done.

Now, if $O(Z(G))= p,\,$ how can I prove that $G$ is abelian ?

Is it by proving that $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic? And if so, then $G$ is abelian.

If yes how to prove that that  $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic?

Comment: If $x\in G$ is not in the center, but $|Z(G)|>1$, then $|Z(G)|=p$. Now the centralizer of $x$ strictly contains the center $Z(G)$ (because it contains $x$), but the order of the centralizer has to divide the order of the group, so its order is $p^2$, but this is only possible if the centralizer of $x$ is the whole group. Therefore the group is abelian.

Comment: First of all, you know $Z(G)$ is normal, so $G / Z(G)$ is a group of order $p$. Now it follows that it is cyclic, let's say it is generated by $hZ(G)$. If you pick ab element of $G$ it will be of the form: $h^{b}z_i$, with $z_i \in Z(G)$. Pick another element and show that they conmute.

Answer (score 4):

Prove the following (easy):

**Lemma:** For *any*  group $\;G\;$, the quotient group $\;G/Z(G)\;$ cannot be cyclic non-trivial.

From the above it follows that $\;G/Z(G)\;$ cyclic $\;\implies G\;$ is abelian.

Answer (score 1):

$o(Z(G))=p$ then $o(G/Z(G))=p$ and every group of prime order is cyclic

Comment: why o(Z(G))=p then o(G/Z(G))=p is true ?

Comment: $o(G/Z(G))=\frac{o(G)}{o(Z(G))}$

Answer (score 1):

First note that $Z(G)$ is non-trivial, by the `class equation`. Hence $Z(G)$ has order $p$ or $p^2$. If $O(Z(G))=p^2$, $Z(G)=G$ and we're done.

If $O(Z(G))=p$, then $Z(G)$ is cyclic, generated by, say, $z$. G/$Z(G)$ also has order p, and hence is cyclic, generated by, say $a$. Now let $g,g'$ two elements of $G$. These can be written as $g=a^n z$, $g'=a^{n'}z',\enspace z,z'\in Z(G)$. Then
\begin{align*}gg'&=(a^nz)(a^{n'}z')=a^na^{n'}z'z&&\text{since $z\in Z(G)$}\\
&=a^{n'}a^nz'z=a^{n'}z'a^nz=g'g.&&\text{since $z'\in Z(G)$}\end{align*}
Thus $G$ is abelian in that case too.

Answer (score 1):

: Let P be a group of order $p^2$
. We know  that every p−group has
non-trivial, so the center $Z(P)$ of $P$ is not trivial.Thus $|Z(P)|$ is either $p$ or $p^2$.In
the latter case, we have $P = Z(P)$, so P is abelian. In the former case, $P/Z(P) $is
a group of order p. We know that groups of prime order p are cyclic, so $P/Z(P)$ is
cyclic. P is abelian so $ Z(P) = P,$ a contradiction

Answer (score 0):

Z(G) is always subgroup of group G therefore by Sylow's first theorem the possibility for

$o(Z(G))=1 \ or \ p \ or \ p^2$ but p groups have nontrivial center thus,$o(Z(G))= p \ or \ 
p^2$ if $o(Z(G))=o(G)$ then G is Abelian(can you prove this?).

Now, Using this lemma if $o(Z(G))=p$

$\;G/Z(G)=\;$ cyclic $\;\implies G\;$ is Abelian.

$\;o(G/Z(G))=p\;$ hence it is cyclic implies that G is Abelian.

Comment: Note that your last line is contradictory since $\;G\;$ is abelian $\;\iff Z(G)=G\;$ , so that it cannot be $\;\left|G/Z(G)\right|=p\;$ ...yet not all is lost as a simple, tiny correction is needed.

Comment: @Timbuc Thanks.